# Android. Different animations between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I have 2 activities, for example FirstActivity (main) and SecondActivity (child).
I need to make transition animations between them but without using

```
overridePendingTransition();
```

only using styles.

So I made animations and my styles.xml looks like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/AnimActivity</item>
</style>

<style name="AnimActivity" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_right</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/activity_up</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/activity_down</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/activity_left</item>
</style>
```

What I need is:

- When open SecondActivity from FirstActivity

  1. FirstActivity moves up from the screen
  2. SecondActivity moves from left to right to the screen

---

- When go back from SecondActivity to FirstActivity

  1. SecondActivity moves left from the screen
  2. FirstActivity moves down to the screen

Everything works fine except one moment: when I'm in **SecondActivity** and press **Back** button, animation works right (FirstActivity moves down and SecondActivity moves left), but when I press **Up** button (in ActionBar) Android uses not CloseEnter[Exit]Animation but OpenEnter[Exit]Animation (up and right translations instead of down and left like with Back button).

---

I have an idea like override tapping Up button like

```
onBackPressed();
```

but it's not right, isn't it?
So is it any way to play another animation on Up button?

Comment: I wonder why you can't use overridePendingTransition but at the same time you could use onBackPressed?